# Find \$H(j\omega)\$ for a function, if I have \$H(s)\$

Tags: phasor

Let's suppose I know that $$H(s) = \frac{-2}{2s+3}$$
I know that \$s=j\omega\$. But how do I find \$H(j\omega)\$ based on this?
That would be $$H(j\omega)=\frac{-2}{2j\omega+3}$$ then what?

Comment: then you're done?

Comment: Isnt any way to find w and replace it I mean?

Comment: \$\omega\$ is the independent variable at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question. \$s=j\omega\$, all you have to do is plug it in and you're done.